# Image atomic addition in a compute shader

Tags: opengl, shader, compute-shader

I have the following compute shader:

```
#version 430

layout(std430, binding=0) buffer wks{
    ivec2 w[];
};

layout(r32i, binding=1) uniform writeonly iimage2D pathTex;

layout(local_size_x = 1, local_size_y = 1, local_size_z = 1) in;

void main(){
    imageAtomicAdd(pathTex, w[0], 1); // line 12
}
```

That gives me this error:

`0(12) : error C1317: qualified actual parameter #1 cannot be converted to less qualified parameter ("im")`

I can't find what I'm doing wrong according to the [OpenGL wiki](https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Image_Load_Store#Atomic_math)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the GLSL 4.50 spec, `imageAtomicAdd()` requires a image variable with the `coherent` memory qualifier.

This makes sense because an atomic add needs to read the old value, add a value to it, and write back the result. Therefore, it needs to be able to both read and write the image.

To make this work, you need to change the declaration to:

```
layout(r32i, binding=1) uniform coherent iimage2D pathTex;
```

As the name indicates, `writeonly` will only work for image operations that exclusively write to the image, like `imageStore()`.